# Using NMock with ByRef parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, nmock

I have to work with an API that uses a lot of by-reference parameters. I'm just beginning to use NMock, and I'm having trouble seeing how to make NMock actually modify one of those by-ref parameters to a specific value. Am I missing something, or does it just not do that? Is there a better way, short of wrapping this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog entry](http://blog.somecreativity.com/2008/11/17/nmock-expectations-for-functions-accepting-ref-and-out-arguments/) appears to cover things, admittedly from a C# perspective.

Basically you want to call `Will()` with a `SetNamedParameterAction`.